# Scroll event calls function an increasing number of times on every scroll inside ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Context**

I have a page on my site where user comments load in. After the comments load, when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, more comments load in. I put this scroll code at the bottom of the AJAX success callback that gets the comments because leaving it outside of the AJAX call makes the AJAX function run multiple times, loading in the same commments twice. The AJAX code goes something like this:

```
function getArticleHighlightResponses() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/articles/getArticleHighlightResponses.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {articleId: articleId, commentId: commentId, contenttype: contenttype, offset: getHighlightArticleResponsesOffset},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(item) {

        //do stuff in here    

        });

        getHighlightArticleResponsesOffset = getHighlightArticleResponsesOffset + 10;

        $(window).on("scroll", debounce(function() {

            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

                <?php if (isset($_GET['getSpecificComment'])) { ?>

                    var commentId = "<?php echo $_GET['commentId']; ?>";
                    var contenttype = "<?php echo $_GET['contenttype']; ?>";
                    getArticleHighlightResponses(commentId, contenttype);

                <?php } else { ?> 

                    getArticleHighlightResponses();

                <?php } ?>

            }

        }, 50));

    }
}); 

}
```

Calling this scroll code inside the AJAX success callback removes the problem of the double comment loading, but every time I scroll to the bottom of the page, the function `getArticleHighlightResponses()` is called twice as much as it was the time before; if I scroll down the page once, it is called once. If I do it again, it is called twice. If I do it again, it is called four times. If I do it two more times for a total of five times, it is called 16 times. This leads to a TON of function calls whenever I scroll to the bottom of the page when I only want the function to be called once.

**Question**

Is there something about the nature of an AJAX success callback that makes events run functions too many times?

Comment: Nope, you are adding callbacks inside your ajax success method. So the more ajax request you make the more callbacks you add.

Comment: @Eldar Is that the reason why the function calls double every time?

Comment: Yes, and not just double callback count will be equal to ajax calls.

Comment: @Eldar Do you know of a way to negate this so that the callbacks don't add up?

Comment: You can move out that code add the `scroll` event handler from the callback. Then you need something like circuit breaker. Once you called `getArticleHighlightResponses` function in your event handler it shouldn't be calling that method again until it finishes. You can use a variable to keep tracking of the status of the ajax call.